# Elementary OS Grub install failed

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm trying to install Elementary OS on my PC via a bootable DVD, and whenever I try running the installer, I keep getting the message `ACPI PCC Probe failed`.

Assuming that this is a graphics issue, I used the `nomodeset` command to bypass it and It started up the installer. The installation goes great until it begins the bootloader install where it shows me the error message `executing grub-install /dev/sda1 failed` and `This is a critical error`. Is there any fix for this?

A point to note, I just switched over from Ubuntu and to do that I removed the Ubuntu partition and fixed the bootloader using easybcd. This may be a reason why grub fails to install.